# Why aren't there Dual-DVI ports on motherboard(s)?

Tags: motherboard, dvi, intel-graphics

Most motherboards I'm looking at doesn't appear to feature a Dual-Link DVI port (which limits max resolution to 1900x1200).

Is the lack of Dual-DVI port a limitation inherent in Intel HD Graphics Processor or a choice made by the motherboard manufacturers?

Comment: DVI has largely been abandoned in favour of HDMI and DisplayPort. According to [Quick Reference Guide for Intel® Core™ Processor Graphics](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics) most recent Intel boards support 4k @ 24/30 Hz over HDMI. As to why they don't support dual link DVI (which requires 4 slower lanes instead of the 3 needed by HDMI) that would be anyone's guess, though it probably has a lot to do with dwindling support for the DVI standard.

Comment: I'd say that is a valid answer. Make it be one?

Answer (score 1):

DVI has largely been abandoned in favour of HDMI and DisplayPort.

According to [Quick Reference Guide for Intel® Core™ Processor Graphics](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics) most recent Intel boards support 4k @ 24/30 Hz over HDMI.

> DisplayPort* 1.2 / eDP*
>
> - H-Processors: 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz (Ultra-HD)
> - U-Processors: 3200 x 2000 @ 60 Hz, 3840 x 2160 @ 30 Hz
> - Y-Processors: 2560 x 1600 @ 60 Hz
>
> HDMI*: 4096 x 2304, 3840 x 2160 @ 24 Hz / 24bpp
>
> DVI: 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz

A more technical reason might be that [HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) only needs 3 fast TDMS lanes while [dual link DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) needs 3 lanes **per link** for a total of 6 lanes.  As the standard has largely been left in the dust the lane speeds have not been upgraded in the way that HDMI has and so to achieve a similar resolution (and still be standards compatible) a lot more wiring is needed in the graphics chip, in the connection between the connector and CPU and further on to the monitor.

As to why DVI has been essentially abandoned, that would be anyone's guess, though it probably has a lot to do with a better, faster and less demanding (wiring and support wise) standard becoming common for other devices. The HDMI standard also supports audio which makes it more useful for TV and other media devices, further relegating DVI to the pile of discarded standards.

Additionally, from the [Wikipedia page on DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface)

> In December 2010, Intel, AMD, and several computer and display manufacturers announced they would stop supporting DVI-I, VGA and LVDS-technologies from 2013/2015, and instead speed up adoption of DisplayPort and HDMI. They also stated: "Legacy interfaces such as VGA, DVI and LVDS have not kept pace, and newer standards such as DisplayPort and HDMI clearly provide the best connectivity options moving forward. In our opinion, DisplayPort 1.2 is the future interface for PC monitors, along with HDMI 1.4a for TV connectivity".

So DVI is pretty much dead in favour of newer and more adaptable standards.

Comment: While generally true, they *can't* abandon neither VGA nor DVI for most low-to-mid range motherboards and IGPUs in office or home settings since they are (I would assume) the main users of integrated graphics.

Comment: The *standards* are abandoned, meaning they are unlikely to ever be updated to allow faster speeds or other capabilities. There might be support for dual-link out there, but if you want higher resolutions then you are going to get better support in HDMI or DisplayPort.

Comment: @JBeurer as a side note dual link DVI will only get you up to 2560 * 1600 which is nowhere near the  3840 * 2160 that DP or HDMI will get you. Even in the workplace I have seen a slow but sure drift away from DVI as almost all dedicated graphics cards have DisplayPort while laptops with integrated graphics almost always have HDMI or eDP for their external outputs. DisplayPort to DVI adaptors are more common than anything else in our office.

Answer (score 0):

There are Dual-Link DVIs on motherboards, just not on the Intel based ones!

AMD motherboards with `AMD A85X` or `AMD A88X` chipsets and `AMD FM2/FM2+` socket have Dual-Link DVI outputs.

So there's an option for you out there who don't need or want dedicated GPU and have *older* dual-link DVI only 27" (2560x1440) or 30" (2560x1600) monitors.